# Fallback Headset SDK being used in VRTK_SDKManager

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive, vrtk

I just reopened a VR project, for the HTC Vive, in Unity 5.5.0f3, after a 2 month hiatus, and upgraded VRTK and SteamVR to their latest.

When I run my project, I'm getting console errors, telling me

> "Fallback Boundaries SDK is being used"

and

> "Fallback Headset SDK being used"

and I should choose "

> the GameObject with the `VRTK_SDKManager`"

and select them there.

Problem is that I'm relatively certain I have no VRTK_SDKManager used anywhere in my app.

Is this a new class or a new requirement?

Comment: For future searchers, the guys at the VRTK slack pointed me to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMz04CqAYjw

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [VRTK release Version 3](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64131), updated package for 5.4.4 and 5.5.1 that contains VRTK_SDKManager Script. You should need to update the VRTK package but i will recommend you to stick with old if **you don't have time** cause maybe new update made enormous change ([**New features of VRTK 3**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vH5zHo6qI84)).

Comment: Thanks, ended up upgrading, and glad I did, they've improved the  structure of library, and it forced me to revisit some of the areas of my code base, that I may have just ignored rather than improved, otherwise

Comment: does it include hand mesh?

Comment: No, I haven't come across that area, what does it do? We've remodelled the controllers ourselves, if that's relevant.

Comment: I just check new feature video, it seems that they have also added hand mesh option